# After adding a slds float left for second line onwards its not aligned to left any suggestion for this?

Tags: lightning-web-components, lwc-dom

```
<div key={rec.Id} class="slds-clearfix slds-float_left">
<h2 class="slds-text-heading_medium slds-hyphenate heading-title">
    {rec.Name__c}
 </h2>
</div>
```

After adding a slds float left for second line onwards its not aligned to left any suggestion for this? U can in below image.

```
.heading-title {
    height: 26px;
    font-family: 'Salesforce Sans';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-size: 20px;
    line-height: 130%;
   /* display: flex;
    align-items: center;*/
    color: #243034;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Please provide the HTML code that you have used.

Comment: @Sneh added html code, Tried with position also. Pls suggest me something here.

Answer (score 0):

The text within the `<h2>` tag might be inheriting `text-align` css from any parent node. To override it, add `text-align: left;` for `.heading-title` class.

Comment: Thanks @Sneh It worked.

Comment: Kindly mark it as best answer if it resolved your issue.